# Is AJAX really asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

When you fire an ajax call, what we typically do in the browser side code is have a "xmlhttp" variable and check for status changes until the response is loaded, which means the client side maintains some sort of connections/thread to the server and the server responds via that connection back to the client. The only difference I see is that the page is not refreshed and that brings me to the very basic question, is ajax really asynchronous?

Compared to JMS where the request is sent and there is absolutely no connection between the Client and Server and the response is sent via different thread initiated by the server. Isn't JMS really asynchronous. I'm confused. Can someone please clarify.

Comment: Asynchronous in AJAX means that you do not get the result immediately after calling `send` (it doesn't block). I don't know why you expect the page to refresh...?

Comment: The request doesn't hold up the progression of JS execution like a synchronous call would? Believe the thread is outside the JS and just informs the engine when it has received new data and needs to initiate a callback. Think theres a flag in the request to perform sync instead if you want to see the difference.

Comment: @jgillich: No. I never meant page refresh. I meant if synchronous really meant getting the response in the same phase/time window, then asynchronous should be out of that phase/time window. but in our case, it is bound to the http connection. That is where I'm confused.

Comment: @nepeo: So, If my understanding is correct, asynchronous is only measured based on the parent context/process which is happening - in this case the JS execution. It is not measured "from the time the request is sent and the response is received or the manner how the request and response is handled in the sub-context". I thought synchronous had something to do with time/phase.

Comment: @spatik measured is a strong word, it's an implementation not an effect. But your right, contextually it is asynchronous relative to the JS runtime. The work is done by a background thread of the browser, parallel, yet linked to the JS thread(remember JS is single threaded/call-stack based). Claudix 's answer is very good, despite his er... creative analogy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is closely to how I understand it. May be I'm incorrect. Asynchronous - meaning not happening in the same order measured w.r.t time. So the real question is asynchronous WHAT? Is it asynchronous request-response, is it Asynchronous Java Script Execution, is it Asynchronous method invocation.

With this concept in mind, when I look at AJAX, it is indeed asynchronous meaning it is asynchronous Java Script execution. "XMLHTTP" usage per-se is synchronous http request-response under the hood of JS. 
JMS on the other hand is asynchronous request-response which I think, shouldn't be confused with the execution of Javascript.

Does this make sense? Can we understand it like this?

Given this,
I think we should expand AJAX as Asynchronous JAvascript eXecution, instead of Asynchronous JAvascript and Xml.

Answer (score 14):

AJAX is said to be asynchronous in the sense that waiting for requests does not block the page's user interface. In other words: when you send a whatsapp message and you actively wait for the reply, then you are doing a synchronous request: no matter if your wife is asking you for going to bed. You won't go to bed until you get the reply. But if you send the message and you still want to do other things like going to bed with your wife, then you'll do an async request: you will read the message when the phone rings (an AJAX onload event).

The UI thread of a web page would be your wife.

Comment: That was a good answer, despite comparing wife to UI thread ;)

Comment: Claudix: are you member of 9gag?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your definition of "asynchronous" but in this case imagine it better as "non-blocking". Allowing you to send multiple requests without blocking other stuff on a page and receive the responses as they come. The time lag between request and response without any blocking is what it makes "asynchronous" in programming. Of course it is bound to HTTP session internally managed by web browser and time out which defines the maximum allowed time lag between request and response.

Comment: I absolutely concur with what you are thinking. I'm sure everyone is also having a pretty close sense of asynchronous/synchronous like the way you mentioned. Still the reason I really asked this question was to know what everyone thinks about asynchronous/synchronous or is there really something under the hood that I'm missing.

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything. I would say - it's a very efficient synchronous mechanism allowing you asynchronous programming :-)

Comment: I will wait some more time, to see other replies until I officially mark your answer as "accept". :) 
Interesting, how the meaning of asynchronous has really merged with non-blocking. A sub-process which is not blocking some other macro process, just makes it asynchronous. :)

Comment: It is indeed. Good question

Comment: Also interesting is to look at the very definition of this word :) http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/asynchronous